# ListPreference get error when choose one of the displayed values

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

How do I fix it? Once I select one item from list of items in ListPreference, I got an error as below.

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.mobilaris.eunomia.client, PID: 2998
>                                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: ListPreference requires an entries
>   array and an entryValues array.

The code as below. The class under SettingsActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_map_layers);
  setHasOptionsMenu(true);

  mapMessagesHandler.getMapLayers();

  final ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("maps_list");

  if(listPreference != null) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> mapsList = MapManager.getMaps();

    for(final int value : mapsList.keySet()) {

      listPreference.setSummary(mapsList.get(value));
      listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
          MapManager.setSelectedMapInstance(value);
          preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntry().toString());
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
    logger.error("No map to select");
  }
}
```

The XML as below.

```
  <PreferenceCategory>

    <ListPreference android:key="maps_list"
                    android:defaultValue="3" />

  </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: What does maps_list look like? Can you post the xml?

Comment: @Timm OMalley I added

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the arrays as the error states: "ListPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array.

Add arrays.xml

```
<resources>
<string-array name="entries_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="entries_values_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Reference the arrays in your ListPreferences

```
<ListPreference android:key="maps_list"
    android:entries="@array/entries_array"
    android:entryValues="@array/entries_values_array"
    android:defaultValue="3" />
```

An example to load the arrays from the mapsList:

```
if(listPreference != null) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> mapsList = MapManager.getMaps();
    String[] entries = new String[mapsList.size()];
    String[] entryValues = new String[mapsList.size()];
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> iter = mapsList.entrySet().iterator();

    int i = 0;
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> mapping = iter.next();
        entries[i] = mapping.getKey().toString();
        entryValues[i] = mapping.getValue().toString();
        i++;
    }
    listPreference.setEntries(entries);
    listPreference.setEntryValues(entryValues);
    listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
          MapManager.setSelectedMapInstance(value);
          preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntry().toString());
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
    logger.error("No map to select");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @TIm, but how could I use the MainActivity to assign to the ListPreference.

Comment: How could I access Stringarray one and two from the MainActivity

Comment: You would need to put the entries from your map into arrays and use setEntries(String[]) and setEntryValues(String[]) or hard code the resource like I did above. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html

Comment: could you give me an example. I am new in this area

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. I don't have the android sdk available so I can't test it.